# Can anyone help me to deal with URL rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm a beginner in the URL rewriting and I have a question. Here is a part of my rules:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/page1/?$ admin/page1.php
RewriteRule ^admin/page2/?$ admin/page2.php
RewriteRule ^admin/page3/?$ admin/page3.php
<more similar lines>
```

All these page(x) are different php files. 
Now rewriting works OK, but is it possible to shorten all this?
For example:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/?$ admin/$1\(.php) (or whatever...)
```

Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is really nice

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]                                                                                                                                                                                              
</IfModule>
```

You put it in your .htaccess then if the URL is, for example /projects/ , in your index.php, you will receive it in argument $_GET['url'] .. then I suggest you to use explode('/', $_GET['url']);

This is the most easy and basic URL rewriting and fit to pratically anything.

If the specified URL is a  present file in the filesystem, it will give you the file, else it will give the URL in a GET argument to your index.php code

Comment: Thanks, I see it's like the Wordpress rewriting.
I think I'm gonna stay with this solution. It's a pity that I'll have to edit some code :)

Comment: This was digged in the CakePHP htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ admin/$2.php?{QUERY_STRING}
```

Code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/?$ admin/$1.php
```

However this will match `admin//` and change it to `admin/.php` which is I'm sure *not* what you want. So, use a `+` instead of a `*`:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)/?$ admin/$1.php
```

---

Note that the rule you have will also match `admin/folderX/pageX`. If you do not want this behavior, try:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ admin/$1.php
```